# Fourier transform of $\mathrm{rec}(x) =\begin{cases} 1 & \text{if }|x| < 0.5,\\ 0.5& \text{if }|x| = 0.5,\\ 0& \text{if }|x| > 0.5 \end{cases}$

Tags: analysis, integration, fourier-analysis

> $$\mathrm{rec}(x) =\begin{cases}
> 1 & \text{if }|x| < 0.5,\\
> 0.5& \text{if }|x| = 0.5,\\
> 0& \text{if }|x| > 0.5
> \end{cases}$$
>   The Fourier transform of this function is $\frac{\sin(\pi u)}{\pi u}$ which we will rename $\mathrm{sinc}(u)$. Show that the Fourier transform of $\mathrm{rec}(x-4) + \mathrm{rec}(x+4)$ is $2(\mathrm{sinc}(u))\cos(8\pi u)$.

I have no idea where to begin on this problem. I cant even see where I will get a cosine at.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if you're using the convention

$$
\mathcal{F}[f(x)](k)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-2\pi ikx}dx,
$$then we have the translation property:

$$
\mathcal{F}[f(x-c)](k)=e^{-2\pi ikc}\hat{f}(k)
$$

You should be able to use this, along with the fact that

$$
\cos(x)=\frac{1}{2}(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})
$$

Comment: I see it now. Your help is much appreciated. Thank you.